# In Hive, how to perform wild card search of a tag value using "regexp_replace()" to replace it with a common value?

Tags: sql, xml, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I have *string* tag occurrences within multiple *Value* families which consists of varying values. I need to make use of `regexp_replace()` to do a wild card search, read all such *string* occurrences & to replace them with a common value "NULL".

Below is a sample XML:

```
<ParentArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Value>
            <string>123</string>
            <string>234</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Value>
            <string>345</string>
            <string>456</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
</ParentArray>
```

The expectation is to read through all *String* tag values and to replace them with NULL.

Comment: do you want <string>NULL</string> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 regexp_replace(str,'(<string>)(\\d+)(</string>)','$1NULL$3')
```

Demo:

```
select "<ParentArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Value>
            <string>123</string>
            <string>234</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Value>
            <string>345</string>
            <string>456</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
</ParentArray>
" as str)

select regexp_replace(str,'(<string>)(\\d+)(</string>)','$1NULL$3') from mydata
```

Result:

```
<ParentArray>
        <ParentFieldArray>
            <Value>
                <string>NULL</string>
                <string>NULL</string>
            </Value>
        </ParentFieldArray>
        <ParentFieldArray>
            <Value>
                <string>NULL</string>
                <string>NULL</string>
            </Value>
        </ParentFieldArray>
    </ParentArray>
```

If you want to replace not only digits in values, including empty values, use:

```
select regexp_replace(str,'(<string>)(.*)(</string>)','$1NULL$3') from mydata
```